# Return to linux command line prompt after executing an HBase shell script

Tags: linux, shell, hbase

I am trying to run an hbase shell script like

```
hbase shell my_script.sh
```

(... and it works fine).

After it is executed I see the hbase shell prompt.
What do I need to do to leave the hbase shell and return to the linux command line after the script is executed?

It's probably a simple problem, but I couldn't figure it out yet.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [here](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/Shell) you can see that command is:

```
 exit
```